# Enviar tabla de productos por email PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, email

¿Cómo puedo mostrar solo las tablas que tienen 1 o más?

Tengo una tabla con nombres, cuando hago clic en enviar correo electrónico solo quiero enviar aquellos que tienen 1 o más.

Esto es lo que estoy tratando de hacer, me las arreglo para hacer la tabla pero no puedo filtrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que hice hasta el momento:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">

    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" require>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" require>

<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>product</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <?php
            while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)){
           ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?= $product['products'] ?></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="quantity" placeholder="quantity" size="2" min="0"></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    <input type="submit">
```

Y esto es lo que hay en el email:

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email =  $_REQUEST['email'];

if ($quantity => 1) {
    echo "mail("mail@myemail.com","Title",$name,$email,$product,$quantity);";
} else {
    echo "Vacío";
}

?>
```

Comment: Que almacenas en **$quantity?**

Comment: Son archivos separados cierto? no veo que declares las variables `$product` ni `$quantity` en el archivo donde recibes los datos, aparte asumo que quieres enviar varios productos entonces la forma en que está no serviría.

Necesitas ponerle a los inputs dinámicos un atributo name para que puedas leerlos por post, recomendaría que uses javascript para tomar los datos del formulario y enviarlos mediante fetch para poder manejarlos de forma mas eficiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- Quieres enviar varios inputs `number` a la vez, lo cual yo te recomiendo que a cada input `number` le agregues el atributo `name` pero como estas enviando varios, tus inputs quedarian de la siguiente forma:

```
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="cantidad[]" placeholder="quantity" size="2" min="0">
```

2.- Nota el corchete **[ ]** en el atributo `name`

3.- En php tendras que manejarlo como un arreglo, entonces podras recorrelo y solo enviar los que tu desees.

```
$productos = $_REQUEST['cantidad'];

foreach($productos as $producto){
    if($producto>=1){
        //REALIZAS LO QUE TENGAS QUE HACER EJEMPLO ENVIAR CORREO
    }
}
```

4.- Te recomiendo que hagas un var_dump() de lo que mandas por ejemplo

```
echo var_dump($_POST);

echo var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Para que puedas ver la información que te llega.